# Print key-value pairs of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How I can print key-value pairs in this situation:

```
a = [
{"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
{"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
{"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
]

search_name = 'Tom'

for i in a:
   for key in i:
      if (i[key] == search_name):
           print (item for item in a).next()
      else:
           print 'No Name'
```

I don't want to see 'No name' message

Comment: Hm, if you don't want to see it then don't print it?

Comment: But I need this message, because if I didn't have name in my dictionary user must receive 'No name'. But even if I have name in my dictionary I still receive message 'No name'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way to achieve it would be:

```
for dic in a:
    name = dic.get('name')  # will return None if dic has no `name` key
    if name and name == search_name:
        print dic
    else:
        print 'No Name'
```

But anyway, if don't wan't to see `No Name` then simply don't print it.

Comment: I need to see this message if I didn't have name in my dictionary, the problem is that I see message even if I have the name in my dictionary

Comment: If I put name that I didn't have in my dictionary, I didn't receive message 'No Name'

Comment: @andrew Ok, this is a very simple change. See if you can do it by yourself.

Comment: I try but I can't. I try to move 'else' below if name == search name I receive the message three times.

Comment: I still receive three times...:)

Comment: @andrew Your intentions are not clear. Of course you get it three times, one time for each dictionary in the list. If you want to get it only one time you will need to use a boolean variable as a flag to indicate if you already printed `No Name` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Of course You see it. You iterate over dictionary keys (`for key in i`) and when You try to match `i["age"]` with `search_name`, it will show `No Name`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for dict in a:
    if search_name in dict.values():
        print dict
    else:
        print "No name"
```

Comment: Twice "No name" message